# University is not issuing me my convocation certificate

Tags: degree, india, certification

I completed my bachelors in Engineering in Aug '16. It's been more than 2 years I haven't received my convocation certificate. Every time I go to university to ask about my convocation certificate the department head says they sent it to college. College says they didn't receive it.

Not sure what I can do more about it. Everyone is rude and they don't have any answers when i question about proof or written statement about my convocation certificate.

I am out of options and thinking of filing formal police complaint. If anyone has any other suggestions regarding this please let me know. And I am sorry for my earlier offensive post.

Comment: I gave you a suggestion before.

Comment: @SolarMike trust me I went there like 10 times and each time I was said with the same answer that they sent it to my college and when I enquired at the college they say they don't have it.

Comment: Right. So, you go to the college, tell the person you are talking to that there is a communication problem since the engineering school says they sent it. Ask the college folks how to resolve the issue. Escalate (politely) as needed. Show them you have done the leg work.

Comment: I don't know anything about India, so why do you need it?

Comment: @AzorAhai It belongs to me and I deserve it. My college where I am enrolled for MBA program needs it.

Comment: Do they need the physical certificate? Here, at least, an official transcript is used to verify any degrees you've earned.

Comment: @AzorAhai yes they've asked about it. They can use the transcript but they have specifically mentioned to get the certificate as well.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Good luck

Comment: @JonCuster I already tried that. I think they messed up something either delivery or didn't even print it in the first place and don't want to bother because they are lazy. You don't know at what length they can go just to avoid some responsibility.

Comment: @noob - Perhaps it is time for you to learn to treat the staff nicely and politely. It never hurts to be kind and friendly to the secretaries and assistants. A smile, a tale of woe by a poor student, and a nice request of what you can do would likely have fixed it all the first time. Assuming they are lazy jerks will result in, well, where you are.

Comment: @JonCuster What if I say there are more cases like me I am not sure how many but I met a guy once when I visited the university office who had similar case like me. And to be frank I never was impolite to them.

Comment: Navigating bureaucracies can indeed be a hard skill to learn, but one well worth working on. There is quite a difference between never being impolite, being polite, being nice, and being ingratiating to others. Moving forward in life, always get to know all the people around you as people. You never know what they can and will do for you.

Comment: I think it doesn't matter if someone is not being nice to you one should do their duty as long as other person is not being offensive. You never know what your irresponsibility will lead to in someone's life. What if someone loses an important job or admission if they don't have certification. When I said that I will lose my admission if I am not able to submit the certificate the lady at the university said and I quote "so what should we do, it's not our problem."

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that it is a lack of communication that is causing your problem, you need a way to create the needed conversation to get the problem resolved.

I'd suggest sending an email to both the department head and the college office explaining the difficulty and asking for a resolution. This should be one mail, addressed to both offices so that you put them in direct communication with each other.

You may learn something from whatever response you get from either or both parties. If the problem goes beyond communication, you need to know that in order to figure out what else might be done.

But you need, also, to phrase things respectfully, even if you don't feel it. Calling names such as you used in an earlier question here will only get you ignored.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I did that will report any progress.